# MySQL realtime similar to Firebase

Tags: mysql, sql, angular, firebase

I've been playing around a bit with Angular4 and Firebase, looking for a solution to a new large and complex project, and although I am getting it to work on basic stuff, Firebase's JSON data schematic is nothing like the SQL I've grown up with and I'm finding it far too foreign to consider building a large and complex webapp on it.

I've been searching for a SQL/MySQL type alternative that will allow Angular4 to subscribe and react to changes on the DB server in realtime but so far haven't come up with anything.

Basically, I want what Firebase achieves but in a more natural SQL type query environment.

Does anyone know of anything like this ?

Comment: Firebase isn't SQL nor does it have a schematic. To understand Firebase, try out this primer [NoSQL Data Modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/). It will be worth the read as Firebase NoSQL is very powerful and easily handle large scale projects - you just need to think in a NoSQL way. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, Thanks Jay. I do understand how it works, but it means ditching 20 years of SQL. So I'm hoping someone knows of a SQL alternative.

Comment: I'm in a search for a full-scale relational SQL style DB Firebase alternative but haven't found one yet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I built and app that was a hybrid of Firebase and MySQL. I used Google App Engine and set up a Firebase "listener" in a java app that consumed changes from the Firebase system. The java app converted the json data into sql inserts into the mysql database. The updates where practically in real time. That way for individual users I had instant lookups on Firebase and when I needed to do aggregation across users I used the MySQL instance. No direct writes to MySQL were allowed.

Comment: Thanks...But that's beyond my skill sets I'm afraid !

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for something that makes MySQL data live for a long time. I understand that Firebase data is not SQL , but what I wanted was to make the database "behave" like Firebase in terms of it's real-time features. (because that's the magic that's makes everyone go WOW when they see a demo of Firebase.)
I think Firebase just uses sockets under the hood...

---

Anyway, there is a good solution to this.

1. Create a nodejs server using these dependencies:
   Express, socketio MySQL mysqlevents (and whatever else you like...for your
   server.
2. when your nodejs server interacts with the db consume MysqlEvents package to
   trigger emits. (options are ALL, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE etc)
3. on the client side use socket io to listen to these events...create obervables

---

```
subscribe to them and you good to go.
```

here's an example video that shows it step by step:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2DQZ5Ew54A&list=PLsjmv9aDmNDDrj3tu6Sj9MGEp2UOlVBoT